# Advices on deploying plotly dash app on github pages

Tags: python, github-pages, plotly-dash

I am knew to plotly dash apps, and I am looking to deploy it for free, to visualise data. I have seen that it is possible to deploy it on render and other pages, but I want to know if is possible to deploy it on github pages

I look at a covid dashboard deployed for github pages, but I found it quite challenging to follow.